# Tablayouts and Fragments equivalent in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift4

I have some sort of following design in the Android app. Now I want to make the iOS version of it. But I am really confused with what components should I make such app.

Please have a look at this picture then I will describe them 1 by 1.

[image]

1. Top tap bar. In android this has been handled using Tablayout. So need to know if Ios has anything like this ?
2. 2nd Top bar. In android it is second tablayout.
3. Bottom bar this is just a custom view for actions we made for all screens

So need to know I want to make a View that has Top bar only and I want to embed some different view controller when user click on top bar buttons. Is it applicable in IOS that way or is there any native control in IOS?

Comment: where is the image ??

Comment: let me edit the question

Answer (score 1):

There is no native control to achieve what you want , I think you have to go custom or use this [library](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip#how-to-change-the-visible-child-view-controller-programmatically) , and nest 2 instances of `XLPagerTabStrip`

Comment: but It has tabs that can be swipped I did not want that

Comment: you can listen for swipe and deactivate i ( return false inside callback) , also look for it's properties

Answer (score -1):

There is a project for material components for iOS [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) and I believe a component called MDCTabBar there is what you need. [Here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/Tabs) is a link for the tab layout you are looking for.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean viewController get change only by clicking on tabs not by swipping . bcz thts the requirement